# cakephp 2.x using 'NOT IN' in subquery

Tags: mysql, cakephp, orm

I have this tiny mysql query(it returns element which dont have 1,3,5 state):

```
SELECT DISTINCT number FROM records WHERE number NOT IN
( SELECT number FROM records WHERE state_id = 1 or state_id = 3 or state_id = 5)
```

In cakephp i am not good at subquery but i was able to do it:

```
    $conditionsSubQuery['`Record2`.`state_id`'] = array(1,3,5);

      $db = $this->Record->State->getDataSource();

      $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(
    array(
        'fields'     => array('`Record2`.`number`'),
        'table'      => $db->fullTableName($this->Record),
        'alias'      => 'Record2',
        'limit'      => null,
        'offset'     => null,
        'joins'      => array(),
        'conditions' => $conditionsSubQuery,
        'order'      => null,
        'group'      => null
    ),
    $this->Record
);

      $subQuery = ' `Record`.`number` NOT IN (' . $subQuery . ') ';

      $subQueryExpression = $db->expression($subQuery);

     $conditions[] = $subQueryExpression;



     $subQuery=$this->Record->find('first', compact('conditions'),
             //array('recursive'=>0),
             array('fields'=>array('Record.state_id')
             ));
```

Maybe i don't understand something good but it is really annoying to get the same result takes tons of code,i know there is $this->query for core mysql
But is there a way in the find to get the same result with just properly used 'conditions'? Or cakephp does not support 'NOT IN' and thats why no easier way?

Update1:
The scheme of the query look like:

```
(1, 'A', 1),
(2, 'A', 2),
(3, 'B', 3),
(4, 'C', 2),
(5, 'B', 1),
```

The result of mysql query retrive only  C, since B has also the value 3,1 same as with A.
Without the 'not in' B is also returned(because of having 1 value too).

I try to make it as clear as possible,i add some additional values to show which fits for the results:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc92a/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood your original query you shouldn't need to use subqueries for this at all.

In CakePHP you can use the keyword `NOT` in the conditions of a find to apply the `NOT` part of your query; to handle the `IN` part just pass an array of options:-

```
$this->Record->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'number'
        )
        'conditions' => array(
            'NOT' => array(
                'state_id' => array(1, 3, 5)
            )
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'number'
        )
    )
);
```

I've used `fields` to limit the response to just the `number` column and used `group` to only return distinctive results.

Otherwise, to use subqueries in Cake 2 the easiest way is to perform the subquery separately and then use that response in the main query. Cake 3's new ORM is better setup for subqueries.

**Update:**

Based on your updated example in the question I think the easiest way of achieving what you want it to do two queries. First to get the record numbers you don't want to include (`$exclude`) and then use that result to exclude them from your results query:-

```
$exclude = $this->Record->find(
    'list',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'id', 'number'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            'state_id' => array(1, 3, 5)
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'number'
        )
    )
);

$result = $this->Record->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'number'
        )
        'conditions' => array(
            'NOT' => array(
                'number' => $exclude
            )
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'number'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: i updated the question to make it clear the result of query.
Also i checked your code,unfortunately it is also return record without (1,3,5) but in the table can have such as values

Comment: @Andrewboy your original SQL would not return any rows in your sample data. Are you looking for cases where records do not exist in all of the given states?

Comment: yes you were right i was not properly setup the scheme but now i updated

Comment: @Andrewboy I think your SQL is still wrong. I've tested this locally and your SQL would return rows 2 and 4. Are you trying to find any letter that only has one or less of the states 1, 3 and 5?

Comment: @Andrewboy your fiddle is not the same as what you are saying in your question. If you are trying to achieve what you've shown in your fiddle then my answer works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72fb7/5/1. Could you clarify exactly what you are trying to query as it is really not clear. :-)

Comment: However the mysql queries was not the same but the result was the same.
The Results:
If an element A has values like A-1,A-4,A-5 i don't want to get it,the result must include only in that case if the values has A-4 in the table
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28ed9/1/0 were the fiddles not clear all?

Comment: @Andrewboy see my updated answer. I think this is what you are trying to achieve based on your updated example in the question.

Comment: thank you it is working properly and its a bit easier than my cakephp subquery. I still miss the shortness of myquery..
Maybe i will check it how this work in 3.x

Answer (score 0):

```
$coupons = $this->Record->find('list',
    array('conditions'=>('Record.id NOT IN (select record_id from record_2)')
));
```

This is what I did.
Hope it helps.